# How should I concat in tensorflow-js?

Tags: node.js, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I'm trying to train data using tensorflow-js.
I need the data to have

- a value (I normalized value)
- a oneHotEncoded flkm_id
- and a label (onHot encoded as well)

When I train only 1 feature (the "value"), I got a successfull accuracy/loss
But when I train also using flkm_id, I believe I should concatenate values with flkm_id but it give me error :

> on the line 108, `const xConcat = tf.concat([x, flkm_id], 1);`
>
> Message: ConcatOp : Expected concatenating dimensions in the range [-1, 1), but got 1

Can you help me to figure out what going on ?

I have the full code including sample data :
https://pastebin.com/KYswwuTA

Thanks.